# Javascript/jQuery - is it possible to encapsulate and return the result of an asynchronously executed function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I know this question has been asked many times in many different ways, but I am still having trouble identifying a good solution to the following problem.

How can I wait for the callback of this asynchronously-executed inner function to complete prior to returning from the outer function?

```
function outer() {
    var result = false;
    var innerAsynch = function() {
        result = true;
    }
    setTimeout(innerAsynch, 1000);
    waitForInnerAsynch(); //blocking
    return result;  //true
}
```

1) I am well aware that this is bad practice for 99.999% of use cases, so please don't tell me that it shouldn't be done!

2) Please feel free to completely restructure this code... my only requirement is that outer() returns something which blocks the browser until innerAsynch() is done and passes the following test:

```
 if(outer()) {
    //1 second later.... yippee!
 }
```

Also I am using jQuery, but I would prefer not to use a plugin unless it really makes sense to do so. Thanks!

**Update**

I want to reiterate that my goal is to fully encapsulate the asynchronous execution within the synchronous call to outer() without arguments.

In other words, this should work:

```
<a href="something" onclick="return outer()">A very slow link</a>
```

Perhaps this is not actually possible, in which case I am fine using callbacks, but I want to develop a better understanding of why that is the case.

Comment: Blocking is not the way to do it in js. Take a look into promises - http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: @bfavaretto - Good suggestion. Before posting I was looking into promise objects but I am having adapting that concept to this example.

Comment: deferred jquery objects are based on callbacks. jQuery just abstracts them

Answer (score 1):

Standard js pattern. You just need to use callbacks:

```
function outer(callback) 
{
    var innerAsynch = function(innerCallback) {
        var result = true;
        innerCallback(result);
    }

    setTimeout(function()
    {
      innerAsynch(function(result)
      {
        callback(result);
      });

    }, 1000);
}
```

Usage:

```
outer(function(result)
{
  if ( result )
    //true
  else
    //false
});
```

Comment: Looks to me like `outer` will return immediately after calling `setTimeout`. How does this answer the question?

Comment: It's really confusing that you use the same variable name `result` in 3 different places, but these are actually different variables (aren't they?).

Comment: The variable result in the function outer was not needed

Comment: I still don't see how this waits for the timeout. `outer` still returns immediately, it's just that the callback function doesn't get called until later. And `outer` doesn't return a value, so it can't be used in an `if`.

Comment: @KirillIvlev -  this works and I have tested in JS Fiddle, but I would like to avoid the callback if possible. Is there not a way for the `outer()` call to take 1 sec and return `true` without a callback argument?

Comment: @kgx not really since you don't  know for sure how much time the function will take. You can accidentally execute your code before the outer function is completed

Comment: @KirillIvlev - I only say 1 second because this is a trivial example and that's the delay in setTimeout(). I am going to update my question to better illustrate how I want this to work.

Comment: Still that's the only way as browsers can't guarantee that they will run the function in exact 1 second. Plus you can't predict how much time will ajax calls take. And other libraries just hide this logic that I've written

Answer (score 1):

> I want to reiterate that my goal is to fully encapsulate the asynchronous execution within the synchronous call to outer() without arguments.

Asynchronous execution and callbacks exist for the sole reason of not blocking. If you really want to block, don't use async code. If you do depend on async functions, re-structure your code to use callbacks. It's simple as that.

JavaScript is single-threaded, so, if you block, the browser will seem to freeze until your code unblocks. When you block, you can't even update the UI to notify the user that some long-running operation is being performed. That's why it's bad. Keep in mind that the language was designed around an event loop and a queue of asynchronous events; trying to go against that will just lead to a big headache.

Comment: I fully understand what you are saying, and I know that this is not a normal request in browser land. I have a very specific use case where I am creating an adapter for iOS confirmation notifications created by Phonegap so that they act like a call to window.confirm() which is a blocking operation.  They use a callback mechanism which I would like to wrap in a synchronous method call, hence the reason I am asking this question.

Comment: If you really want it to behave like `window.confirm()`, I guess your only option is writing it in native Objective C code, and then add a js interface to it. Native code should be able to block the whole `UIWebView` thread (but I know very little about Phonegap and Obj C, so correct me if I'm saying something stupid). In JS/HTML you must use an overlay div to block the UI, and create a modal-like dialog on top of that. JavaScript does not provide any way to block as you wish to do, hence the headache I mentioned...